# How to validate/check input time is greater than sysdate in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

OTHER_BLOCK is the block where my textbox TIME_OUT is found.
[screenshot of the form and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGVVK.jpg)
my code is below:

```
IF :OTHER_BLOCK.TIME_OUT <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS')
THEN MESSAGE('TIME OUT SHOULD BE GREATER THAN TIME IN!');
RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END IF;
```

Comment: Please **tell us what the error is**. Not everybody can access images in a pastebin.

Comment: Change your code to `THEN MESSAGE('TIME OUT '||:OTHER_BLOCK.TIME_OUT||' SHOULD BE GREATER THAN TIME IN!');` This should show you why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are not comparing dates with dates...

**Try this:**

```
IF to_date(:OTHER_BLOCK.TIME_OUT,'HH24:MI:SS')  <=  to_date(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
    THEN MESSAGE('TIME OUT SHOULD BE GREATER THAN TIME IN!');
    RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END IF;
```

Comment: it says:
WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-01850.

Comment: @P.Navin `ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23`. What is the value of your input field? Is it set to a  proper time ?

Comment: in the property palette of the textbox where i input the time , the data type is: TIME and the format mask is blank because when i tried HH24:MI:SS, it would return errors

Comment: @P.Navin It seems, from your answer, that there are some other problems in your form ... if it is time field - then, one would expect it to accept time format mask ...  anyhow, what I asked was - what is the value of the field `:OTHER_BLOCK.TIME_OUT`, cause the error has to do with its value...

Comment: i input 22:45:00 when the system time was 22:40:30 but still i am getting the error "WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-01850."

Answer (score 0):

The below code

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
```

will consider current month's start date + SYSDATE's TIME. So handle it properly.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit rather than calling an approach *stupid* (where are your manners,man?) - just propose your own solution (if you have one!) and explain why is it better...